# Globalizing source code

Tags: visual-studio, globalization

I'm running an open source project and every now and then Chinese users report build errors due to unrecognized escape sequences .cs and .js files. When they paste the files as they see them I notice that the Latin characters are changed into Chinese.

I'm using Visual Studio and when I look at "Advanced Save Options" the setting is "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252".

Should I be using Unicode (UTF-8 with signature)? Is there a way to convert all files in the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use UTF-8 (or UTF-16) so you can handle all characters. Codepage 1252 is almost the same as ISO-8859-1 but that can't handle Chinese characters. Here is a [link](http://intertwingly.net/stories/2004/04/14/i18n.html) that can be of interest.